# Maintain position in Symfony form Collection type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

I have an (Doctrine-managed) entity that's being manipulated through a Symfony form - 'Episode'.

The object has a one-to-many Doctrine ArrayCollection property which allows 'Audio' entities to be associated with an Episode.

A user should be able to create Audio objects for different parts of the Episode, e.g. Part 1, 2, etc. But in any order (so just create Part 2 in one session, create Part 1 in another session).

I've tried to model this on a form with a collection, adding a hidden field index and a relevant property on the audio entity, so that when you update a new Audio object it sets the index. This works fine on the first attempt, but when you add another the previous objects lose their index property.

I'd like to avoid just having part1, part2 properties on the Episode object to ease scaling it to more parts and having to add a property each time.

Is there a simple way I'm missing to allow users to create entities in the collection at specific indexes (and possibly with nothing at "index 0")?

Comment: Something is not clear. The Audio object has a "index" property, right? And the user can set this property when filling the form, right?

Comment: The form is customised to guide the user, so all they see is a field for Part 1, Part 2 etc., with a hidden field that sets the appropriate index for that component. I'm using AJAX to submit each part in 2 turn as it is "set", so I'm only posting the element in question - I wonder if this has an impact on the indexes of the other objects?

Comment: I still don't understand. Please post the code for the Episode entity class and the Audio entity class.